# Is it possible to dual boot MacOS alongside another MacOS on Apple Silicon Macs? (Work and play)

Tags: bootcamp, startup, dual-boot

Due to requirements from our secops team, the only way I'm allowed to use my laptop for non work purposes (gaming, personal projects, etc) is if I'm able to install a separate MacOS install alongside my existing MacOS install (dual boot).

(I've worked for a couple weeks to win this compromise - nothing else is acceptable)

I've seen people install MacOS beta alongside MacOS current, is it possible to install MacOS current alongside MacOS current (dual boot) on the new M1 MacBook pros?

Perhaps via bootcamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can dual boot two MacOS's alongside each other. [How to do it](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208891)

Comment: Hello, mileshenry. This is considered a "link-only" answer. It would be helpful for future visitors to this question if you would [edit] in a summary of that page. Links can become broken or outdated so a summary would still provide the necessary information.